# Swift "Scanner" stuck in infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CSV formatted similar to this

```
"1.0","remainder1",
"2.0","remainder2",
"3.0","remainder3",
"4.0","remainder4",
"5.0","remainder5"
```

And I'm looking to scan and print the values using the following:

```
    var textScanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: textToScan)
    textScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\",")

    var value: Double = 0.0
    var remainder: NSString?

    while !textScanner.isAtEnd {

        textScanner.scanDouble(&value)
        textScanner.scanUpTo("\n", into: &remainder)

        print("value \(value)")
        print("remainder \(remainder)")

        print("\n newline \n")
    }
```

It correctly picks up that `value` is a double and `remainder` is a string.  But it's stuck in an infinite loop and keeps printing the same results over and over again.

If I change from scanning a double to a string then it moves forward and finishes properly:

```
textScanner.scanUpTo(",", into: &value)
```

But I really want to scan the first value directly into a `double` instead of a `string` and then casting it back to a `double` for particular reasons.

What am I missing in my first implementation to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. Always check the return value of `scan...` to be sure it actually scanned what you thought.
2. `scanUpTo` does not include the string you are scanning up to. So the scanner is left pointing to the newline, not the character after the newline.
3. Declare variables only where you need them.

Your code should look more like this:

```
var textScanner: Scanner = Scanner(string: csv)
textScanner.charactersToBeSkipped = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\",")

var cnt = 0 // for testing only

while !textScanner.isAtEnd {
    var value: Double = 0.0
    var remainder: NSString?

    if textScanner.scanDouble(&value) && textScanner.scanUpTo("\n", into: &remainder) {
        // Ignore the newline
        textScanner.scanString("\n", into: nil)

        print("value \(value)")
        print("remainder \(remainder)")

        print("\n newline \n")
    } else {
        print("oops")
    }

    // For testing to avoid infinite loop    
    cnt += 1
    if cnt > 10 {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Some of my values are optional, so this was causing problems, but your tips led me to an idea around this and I've got it working now.